# Вопрос по написанию *.bat файла.

Tags: windows, bat, cmd

Почему в цикле не присваивается переменной **"tes"** значение переменной цикла - **%%i** ?

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /B') do (
SET tes="%%i" // не присваивает
echo %tes%  // Ничего не выводит...
)
```

И как вообще можно изменять переменную %%i в цикле, как например, это можно с остальными:

```
%var:~0,3%
```

Вообщем, вот весь отладочный код, который не работает все по той же причине:

```
cd C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop
color 0a
chcp 65001
cls
ECHO OFF
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /B') do (
SET tes="!i!"
echo %tes%
)
pause
```

Comment: Не уверен, что скобки здесь уместны (закрывающая в любом случае потеряна). М.б. хотелось отложенного расширения `!переменных!`?

Comment: Скобку добавил, спасибо. Вот только как изменять %%i в цикле?

Comment: @Dexter, я скобками редко пользуюсь, сейчас попробую как они работают с for...

Comment: Ok, спасибо за содействие. Надеюсь, безрезультатно не кончится это дело...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё понял, зло в скобках. Команды, заключенные в скобки всё равно интерпретируются, как одна строка. Нужно отложенное расширение.

```
@ECHO OFF
REM стыдоба.cmd
SETLOCAL
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%f IN ('dir /b') DO (
    IF "%%f" == "Porno" ( 
        COLOR c 
        SET bacon="%%f"
        REM На самом деле присваивает
        SET bacon
        REM Но не подставляет
        ECHO !bacon!
        PAUSE 
    ) ELSE ( 
        ECHO %%f 
        COLOR
    )
)
```

Интертрепатор командных строк д.б. запущен с ключом `/V:ON`

Comment: Да, вот, скорее в этом-то и ключ, в ключе V. Как его включить из уже запущенно cmd ?

Comment: Надеюсь, вы мне поможете...в любом случае, спасибо вам.

Comment: @Dexter, `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`

Comment: @karmadro4, спасибо большущее! Вот только оказывается, что никакого "зла" в скобках-то и нет. Проблему решает именно установка параметра /C для терминала. Это так, потому что данный код прекрасно работает и без условия:

      FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN ('DIR /b') DO (
SET sp="%%i"
echo !sp!
)

Comment: @Dexter, прочитайте еше раз второе предложение, в нём суть. Напомню, что батники интерпретируются **построчно**.

Эту задачу можно решить без составных команд, через подпрограммы. (`... DO CALL :SUB %%i`)